# :after pseudoelement is cropped when using filter in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter, pseudo-element

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#target {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #F00;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#F00,endColorstr=#F00)";
}
#target:before {
    content: "content from before";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: cyan;
}
```

here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8BzW6/

If you comment the filter then the "after" element is not cropped by the parent element (#target).

Do you know how to solve this?

(I need a gradient and I don't want to use an image)

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft's filter for me is a bad practices, it will always cause issues. And if you combine it with modern technics like CSS3 its getting even worse.

What about using inline 1px gradient image using data64?

Here is a generator: http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/